# Can't start script via screen command

Tags: bash

I have a script, and I want to make it work in background after boot. Therefore, I added the command below into rc.local. However, it doesn't work.

```
sudo -iu executerroot screen -dmS test bash -c "bash /home/pi/FileServer/Run; exec bash"
```

Also I've tried commands in https://askubuntu.com/questions/261899/run-a-screen-session-on-boot-from-rc-local site but no one worked for me. If I execute

```
sudo -iu executerroot screen -dmS test bash -c "bash /home/pi/FileServer/Run; exec bash"
```

I get this:

```
bash: /home/pi/FileServer/Run/: No such file or directory
```

while it doesn't work for real files. When I type "screen -r" I get just blank bash screen if a file exists.

I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Please explain why it happens and how can I solve this.
Thanks...

Comment: Is it `Run`, `RunRR`, or `Run/`?

Comment: Hmm sorry, the script is Run but the output was wrong. I'm having it corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

After years, I got a similar problem today. This time I was trying to call the screen program inside `crontab`. I realized I needed absolute paths and correct bash version in `crontab` **as well as in the script itself**.

I think I had done a similar mistake 6 years ago. I wrote similar program today, probably, due to different environment variables, script didn't be able to find programs (in my case `openvpn`). Even `program &> output.txt` didn't work. The problem was the different bash version not supporting output redirection. I used `/usr/sbin/bash -c "command"` to cope with it. Also, `openvpn` is not in the path in that `crontab` environment, so I had to call it with absolute path (like `/usr/sbin/openvpn`). Then, it worked.